# Namespaced object prototype

Tags: javascript

I'd like to enhance an object with some extra methods, for example add `first()` or `second()` methods to arrays but with a namespace so that it is called in the way `[1, 2].item.second()`, not `[1, 2].second()`. I got code like below but I'm getting `undefined`.

```
Array.prototype.item = {
    first: function () {
        return this[0];
    },
    second: function () {
        return this[1];
    }
};

[1, 2].item.second()
// undefined
// I don't want to use [1, 2].second()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` in your `first()` and `second()` functions refers to the `item` property of the array, not to the array itself and that's why you're getting `undefined`.

The easiest way would be to capture the correct context by turning `item` into a method, as follows:

```
Array.prototype.item = function() {
  var _this = this;

  return {
    first: function() {
      return _this[0];
    },
    second: function() {
      return _this[1];
    }
  };
};
```

Then:

```
[1, 2].item().first(); // 1
[1, 2].item().second(); // 2
```

---

As per your update, if you insist on the original property syntax, you can try the following:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'item', {
  get: function() {
    var _this = this;

    return {
      first: function() {
        return _this[0];
      },
      second: function() {
        return _this[1];
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Then:

```
[1, 2].item.first(); // 1
[1, 2].item.second(); // 2
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: I'd like to achieve `[1, 2].item.first();` though.